# In Flutter, how do I style the label text in textformfield when in focus?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to make the hint text to appear inside the textformfield when in focus, rather than at the top edge.

Currently it looks like this
[Image of textformfield with labeltext sitting at the edge when in focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Txbw.png)

But I want the labeltext to appear inside the textformfield

[Image of textformfield with labeltext inside the field when in focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH0gB.png)

```
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final InputDecorationTheme inputTheme = Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme;

return TextFormField(
  enabled: enabled,
  key: this.customKey,
  controller: textEditingController,
  initialValue: initialValue,
  inputFormatters: isNumericalOnly
      ? [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.singleLineFormatter,
        ]
      : [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.singleLineFormatter,
        ],
  keyboardType: isNumericalOnly ? TextInputType.number : TextInputType.text,
  focusNode: focusNodeToggle,
  maxLength: maxLength,
  validator: (String? value) {
    return validator != null ? validator!(value.toString()) : null;
  },
  onSaved: (String? value) {
    return onSaved != null ? onSaved!(value.toString()) : null;
  },
  onChanged: (String? value) {
    return onChanged != null ? onChanged!(value.toString()) : null;
  },
  buildCounter: maxLength != null && isCounterVisible == true
      ? (BuildContext context, {int? currentLength, int? maxLength, bool? isFocused}) =>
          Container(child: Text('$currentLength/$maxLength'))
      : (BuildContext context, {int? currentLength, int? maxLength, bool? isFocused}) => null,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
    hintText: customHintText,
    helperText: customHelperText,
    helperMaxLines: 2,
    border: inputTheme.border,
    focusedBorder: inputTheme.focusedBorder,
    filled: inputTheme.filled,
    fillColor: inputTheme.fillColor,
    labelStyle: inputTheme.labelStyle,
    label: Text.rich(
      TextSpan(
        children: <InlineSpan>[
          WidgetSpan(
            child: Text(
              label.toString(),
            ),
          ),
          WidgetSpan(
              child: isDataloading
                  ? LoadingIndicator(
                      width: 15,
                      height: 15,
                    )
                  : Text('')),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
); here
```

Comment: Just visit here , it might help you https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the above result by wrapping your `TextFormField` with a container and giving the container some border and padding. Then make all the borders of `TextFormField` like `focusedBorder`, `enabledBorder`, etc to **transparent color**.

Take a look at the following snippet. It will be clear to you. I have also added a GIF as a proof of concept.

```
Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 2), borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
      child: TextFormField(decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "TextField",focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)))),
   )               
  )
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Do you know how to prevent the label size getting smaller on focus?